# Why can't I use javascript setInterval with a function in an external file?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

The following works perfectly fine...displays an alert every 10 seconds

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function letsTest(){
        alert("it works");
    }
    var uptimeId = window.setInterval(letsTest, 10000);
</script>
```

But when I place my `letsTest` function in a file called javaScript.js, it no longer works.

main page:

```
<script src='lib/javaScript.js' type='text/javascript'>
    var uptimeId = window.setInterval(letsTest, 10000);
</script>
```

javaScript.js

```
function letsTest(){
    alert("it works");
}
```

I verified a thousand times over the path and spelling. I use my `javaScript.js` in other places as well. Is it possible to set an interval with a function from another file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<script src='lib/javsScript.js' type='text/javascript'>
    var uptimeId = window.setInterval(letsTest, 10000);
</script>
```

You cannot provide both a `src` and a body for a `<script>` tag. One or the other.

You'll have to use two `<script>` tags:

```
<script src='lib/javaScript.js'></script>

<script>
   var uptimeId = setInterval(letsTest, 10000);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually the reason behind it may be ,that the variable uptimeId is not accessible inside the file javascript.js.
Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: You are wrong. It is a global variable, it's accessible everywhere, and he's not even *trying* to access it inside the external file. I've already posted the reason why this isn't working.